# Draw circle svg orthogonal projections

Tags: javascript, svg, geometry, orthogonal

I need to get the svg path of a circle projected in a orthogonal space.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQYid.png)

What I want to do is create a function(in js) that has the following parameters:

1. the position of the circle
2. the radius
3. and what panel is the circle parallel to
4. axes inclination

This is the function I use to create a simple circle (without perspective)

```
function getPath(cx,cy,r){
  return "M" + cx + "," + cy + "m" + (-r) + ",0a" + r + "," + r + " 0 1,0 " + (r * 2) + ",0a" + r + "," + r + " 0 1,0 " + (-r * 2) + ",0";
}
```

I don't want to approximate the circle creating thousands of points and projecting them all, I want to have a path the accurately describes the projected circle

What can I do?

Comment: Use a CSS 3d transform to transform all the shapes

Comment: *"3. and what panel is the circle parallel to"* how do you describe/define these panels?

Comment: Maybe I'm not getting your use case right, but isn't it better to just use an [SVG transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform)?

Comment: @RecencyEffect An SVG transform cannot do a non-affine projecting if that's what the OP really wants.

Comment: He does say "orthogonal projections". Those are affine, no? (honest question, my math knowledge is not that great)

Comment: @RecencyEffect yes, they will be an affine project. Rotations and shear should be sufficient.

Comment: It would probably help if you stated what the input parameters are.  What do you know about the circle to start with.  Do you have the projection matrix, or what?

Answer (score 2):

I'm pulling something from an unpublished project and hope it makes sense for you.

Suppose you have two tupples of three points, describing two triangles, find the transform matrix between the two. - They could describe the square enclosing a circle, like this:

[image]

Generate the transformation matrix from two point lists:

```
var source = [s0, s1, s2]; // each point as coordinates {x, y}
var target = [t0, t1, t2];

function generate (source, target) {
    var transform = [
        {
            a: 1, b: 0, c: 0, d: 1,
            e: target[2].x,
            f: target[2].y
        },
        {
            a: 1, b: 0, c: 0, d: 1,
            e: -source[2].x,
            f: -source[2].y
        }
    ];
    source.forEach(point => {x: point.x - source[2].x, y:  point.y - source[2].y});
    target.forEach(point => {x: point.x - source[2].x, y:  point.y - source[2].y});

    var div = source[0].x * source[1].y - source[1].x * source[0].y;
    var matrix = {
        a: (target[0].x * source[1].y - target[1].x * source[0].y) / div,
        b: (target[0].y * source[1].y - target[1].y * source[0].y) / div,
        c: (target[1].x * source[0].x - target[0].x * source[1].x) / div,
        d: (target[1].y * source[0].x - target[0].y * source[1].x) / div,
        e: 0,
        f: 0
    };
    transform.splice(1, 0, matrix);

    return transform.reduce(function (m1, m2) {
        return {
            a: m1.a * m2.a + m1.c * m2.b,
            b: m1.b * m2.a + m1.d * m2.b,
            c: m1.a * m2.c + m1.c * m2.d,
            d: m1.b * m2.c + m1.d * m2.d,
            e: m1.a * m2.e + m1.c * m2.f + m1.e,
            f: m1.b * m2.e + m1.d * m2.f + m1.f
        }
    }, { a: 1, b: 0, c: 0, d: 1, e: 0, f: 0 });
}
```

Now, if you have an **absolute** arc command described as an object `arc`

```
{ rx, ry, rotation, large, sweep, x, y }
```

the transformation could be applied like this:

```
function arc_transform (transform, arc) {
    var co = Math.cos(arc.rotation/180*Math.PI),
        si = Math.sin(arc.rotation/180*Math.PI);
    var m = [
        arc.rx * (transform.a * co + transform.c * si),
        arc.rx * (transform.b * co + transform.d * si),
        arc.ry * (transform.c * co - transform.a * si),
        arc.ry * (transform.d * co - transform.b * si),
    ];
    var A = (m[0] * m[0]) + (m[2] * m[2]),
        B = 2 * (m[0] * m[1] + m[2] * m[3]),
        C = (m[1] * m[1]) + (m[3] * m[3]),
        K = Math.sqrt((A - C) * (A - C) + B * B);

    if ((transform.a * transform.d) - (transform.b * transform.c) < 0) {
        arc.sweep = !arc.sweep;
    }

    return {
        rx:  Math.sqrt(0.5 * (A + C + K)),
        ry:  Math.sqrt(0.5 * Math.max(0, A + C - K)),
        rotation: Math.abs((A - C) / B) < 1e-6 ? 90 : Math.atan2(B, A - C)*90/Math.PI,
        large: arc.large,
        sweep: arc.sweep,
        x: transform.a * arc.x + transform.c * arc.y + transform.e,
        y: transform.b * arc.x + transform.d * arc.y + transform.f
    };
};
```

Comment: Could you not just apply the transform matrix to the arc (or circle) element?

Comment: @PeterCollingridge Sure, but the OP stated " I want to have a path the accurately describes the projected circle".