# Animate svg paths on hover in all browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, css-animations

Im new to SVG and paths on HTML5 and I have some issues with an animation im trying to do:

In the next link its a preview of what im trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/fxwL68hr/1/

The problem is: **only works on Google Chrome and Firefox Developer Edition**.

In summary: When I hover the SVG, all the triangles do an animation. However triangles 3 and 4 actually change the paths coords to create a bigger triangle. How I can animate this change of coords in those triangles without using `css d: path()` so it can work in all (or at least the majority of) browsers.

Comment: Use SMIL and fakesmile to support IE/Edge

Comment: @RobertLongson that "could" help about the browser but not how to start the animation on hover.

Comment: FYI on MacOS 10.13.6, I have completely different results in each browser: Firefox (61.0.2), Chrome (68.0.3440.106) and Safari (11.1.2). All have working animation on hover, however the pieces rotate differently in each browser.

Comment: trigger the SMIL via an onmouseover event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There always is a finite transform from one triangle to another. The math behind that is non-trivial, but with a bit of fiddling around with the grafical transformation tool for example of Inkscape, you can find it. That way, I got to the following:

- triangle 3: `matrix(0, 1.92308, -1,0.634615, 75, -120.673)`
- triangle 4: `matrix(0, -2.14286, 2.98507, -2.30277, -123.881, 352.708)`

**Addendum**: *I have done the appropriate math now. I've even described it already in the context of another answer: [Draw circle svg orthogonal projections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48252112/draw-circle-svg-orthogonal-projections/48253141#48253141). While in that answer, three points were used to describe a square that then underwent an orthogonal projection, the mathematical content is just this: take three separate points (not in one line) as source and another three points (same constraints) as target, and the function `generate()` quoted in that answer will give you the transform matrix.*

The animation has to run between the neutral `matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)` and the one above as a `transform` property. See it working in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jk7so0p4/).

Downside: according to [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d), IE does not support CSS transforms on SVG elements, but that was also true for your first two triangles.

In addition, why don't you use a CSS [transition](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transitions-1/) instead of an [animation](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-animations-1/)? You go from one state to a second and back. Describe the base state and the hover state and `transition: transform 1s ease` does the rest.

Comment: I actually think of the transition first, but I was practicing with animation and then i worked around SVG. I dont really get the matrix() thing, how it can be applied to the code i had?

Comment: `matrix()` is a CSS transform function, you can set it as a property just like `translate()` or `rotate()`

Comment: Thanks so much, I will try it later

Comment: It actually works, and really smooth. Thanks for the answer

Comment: But i still dont have a clue how it manage to do that, how did you use Inkscape to get that?

Comment: Understandable, it has to do mostly with familiarity with the tools, and would be complicated to describe in words. On the other hand, I now remembered that I already posted the mathematical answer elsewhere. See the edit.

Answer (score 1):

The next link is a : [CodePen with my solution](https://codepen.io/enxaneta/pen/f6a9a77d60ef313df014dd12f13e5210)
I'm not very sure you will like it.

In the HTML I'm adding a `defs` element with the target path for triangles 3 & 4:

```
<svg id="svg" class="svg_bg" width="50%" viewBox="0 0 100 75">
  <defs>
    <path id="t3Target" d="M 100 75 L 0 0 L 0 75 Z" />
    <path id="t4Target" d="M 100 75 L 100 0 L 0 0 Z" />
  </defs>
    <path id="triangle1" class="triangle1" d="M 17.5 28.5 L 55 75 L 81 75 Z"></path>
    <path id="triangle2" class="triangle2" d="M 36.5 8 L 54.5 75 L 87 75 Z"></path>
    <path id="triangle3" class="triangle3" d="M 110 -25 L 38 75 L 77 75 Z"></path>
    <path id="triangle4" class="triangle4" d="M 49 75 L 84 75 L 120 41.5 Z"></path>
</svg>
```

For the triangles 3 & 4 I'm using JavaScript.

```js
let rid = null;
let shapesRy = [];

class Shape{
  constructor(path_a,path_b,morphingPath){
    this.target = getArgsRy(path_a);
    this.vals = getArgsRy(path_b);
    this.morphingPath = morphingPath;
    this.memory = [];
    for(let i=0; i < this.vals.length; i++){
    this.memory[i] = [];
    this.memory[i][0] = this.target[i].slice();
    this.memory[i][1] = this.vals[i].slice();     
    this.updatePath();
    }
  }

 updateValues() {
 for(let i = 0;i < this.memory.length; i++){ 
    let dist_x = this.target[i][1] - this.vals[i][1]; 
    let vel_x = dist_x/10;
    this.vals[i][1] += vel_x;

    let dist_y = this.target[i][2] - this.vals[i][2];
    let vel_y = dist_y/10;
    this.vals[i][2] += vel_y;
 }

    let dist_x = this.target[0][1] - this.vals[0][1]; 
    if (Math.abs(dist_x) < .01) {
    if(rid){window.cancelAnimationFrame(rid);
    rid = null;
    }

  }
}

 updatePath() {  
  let d=`M${this.vals[0][1]},${this.vals[0][2]}`;
  for(let i = 1;i < this.vals.length -1; i++){
  d += `L${this.vals[i][1]},${this.vals[i][2]}`
  }
  d +="Z"; 
  this.morphingPath.setAttributeNS(null, "d", d);
}
}


shapesRy.push(new Shape(t3Target,triangle3,triangle3));
shapesRy.push(new Shape(t4Target,triangle4,triangle4));



function Frame() {
  rid = window.requestAnimationFrame(Frame);
  shapesRy.map((s) => {
      s.updateValues();
      s.updatePath();
  })
}

svg.addEventListener(
  "mouseover",
  function() {
    if (rid) {
      window.cancelAnimationFrame(rid);
      rid = null;
    }   
    shapesRy.map((s) => {
     for(let i = 0;i < s.memory.length; i++){
       s.memory[i].reverse();
       s.target[i] = s.memory[i][1].slice();
     }
    })
    Frame();
  },
  false
);

svg.addEventListener(
  "mouseout",
  eAction,
  false
);

function eAction(){
  {
    if (rid) {
      window.cancelAnimationFrame(rid);
      rid = null;
    }

    shapesRy.map((s) => {
     for(let i = 0;i < s.memory.length; i++){
       s.memory[i].reverse();
       s.target[i] = s.memory[i][1].slice();
     }
    })
    Frame();
  }
}

function getArgsRy(path) {
    let d = path.getAttribute("d").replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, ""); //remove breaklines
    if (d.charAt(0) == "m") {
      d = "M" + d.slice(1);
    }
    let argsRX = /(?=[a-zA-Z])/;
    let args = d.split(argsRX);

    let ArgsRy = [];

    args.map(arg => {
      let argRy = arg
        .slice(1)
        .replace(/\-/g, " -")
        .split(/[ ,]+/);
      argRy.map((p, i) => {
        if (p == "") {
          argRy.splice(i, 1);
        }
      });

      for (let i = 0; i < argRy.length; i++) {
        argRy[i] = parseFloat(argRy[i]);
      }

      argRy.unshift(arg[0]);
      ArgsRy.push(argRy);
    });

    return ArgsRy;
  }
```

This is a blog post where I'm explaining the code: [Morphing in SVG - first steps](https://codepen.io/enxaneta/post/morphing-in-svg-first-steps)

There is an additional problem with the CSS animation for the triangles 1 & 2 (your CSS) since CSS transforms on SVG elements are extremely buggy.

You may want to read this article: [Transforms on SVG Elements](https://css-tricks.com/transforms-on-svg-elements/)

Alternatively you may want to use JavaScript for all 4 triangles.

Comment: This actually helped me but there is a small issue, when the page load, it doesnt do the default animation of "creating" the triangles".. is there a way to activate the mouseout event when loading the page?

Comment: Hi @enxaneta, nice to see an experienced Frontender around. For this Q&A format, it is preferable to have self-contained posts. So while it is perfectly ok to link to your tutorial, your code example would benefit from being a bit more self-explanatory - like writing a few comment lines explaining the function/class signatures. Also the tutorial does not cover the `requestAnimationFrame` loop or the path parser.

Comment: Hi @alejandro-maliachi-quintana, I've added an window on load event. Please check again my pen.

Comment: Hi @ccprog  Thank you very much for your comment and your kindness. I'll read about self-contained posts at stackoverflow.